# Coverity: static analysis - ignore first time warnings

Tags: static-analysis

I am running coverity on windows and am wondering is there a way to ignore all warnings on the first run and start fresh only showing warnings added in new code??

Comment: Which platform are you targeting, .NET, Java, C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Coverity 4.x this is quite easy; just view all the defects in the first run and mark them as “Pending” (*not* false), and then view only untriaged defects.  In later versions, the user interface is less convenient, but the basic idea is the same.  (For the record, I don’t think you should simply disregard all defects in your existing code.  If they have a high false positive rate, you need to tweak your configuration; otherwise they deserve to be looked at eventually. I say a bit more about this in [my Dr Dobb’s article](http://www.drdobbs.com/testing/deploying-static-analysis/240003801).)